# NodeJS child_process send data to app?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to read\write data if i spawn windows calculator process ? And how to do that ?

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var calcWin = spawn('calc');
```

stdin\stdout with event on 'data'\'message' not working.

Comment: `calc` doesn't take input or output in any accessible fashion.

Comment: So is there way to modify numbers inside calc using nodejs ?

Comment: Processes running any UI won't take input from `stdin`. If you have any command line tools like [GNU bc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/) then it is possible to read output from `calcWin.stdout`'s `data` event